# What is the equivalent of Dart's StreamController in Java?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have to convert the source from a Flutter project into Java Android, but i couldn't find the way to do with **StreamController**, is there any guide or advise?

Answer (score 0):

Subject(BehaviourSubject,..) in RxJava; it can help you;
but I still cannot find any class like streamcontroller in java without RxJava.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30360914)